# Use of Getdate() and date not recognized but in my table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I want to destroy orders in ArchiveCommands from one or
several customers, to delete these ArchiveClient clients, but to
only if these clients do not have orders in ArchiveCommands
of the last year. If these customer have orders in the last year
the deletion of the customers (and their orders) must be prohibited.

But I don't no why the value datecom is not recognized.

> Invalid column name: 'datecom'.

However he is in my table, it's not logic.

```
CREATE TABLE ArchiveCommandes (
nocom int, 
montcom int, 
nocli int, 
datecom datetime
)

CREATE TABLE ArchiveClient (
nocli int, 
ctotmont int, 
nbcom int
)
```

And here is my trigger :

```
create trigger detruit_commandes on ArchiveCommandes
for delete 
as 
if datediff(day, datecom , getdate()) < 365
begin 
raiserror('Suppression des clients et de leurs commandes interdite', 16, 1)
rollback transaction
end
begin
delete a
from ArchiveClient a 
join deleted d on a.nocli = d.nocli
end
```

Comment: `datediff(day, datecom , getdate())` is your problem. What, and where is `datecom` coming from? You still need to declare a object it's coming from, even if that object is `deleted`. This would be akin to writing the query `SELECT CustomerName;` and expecting the data engine to know that the column is located in the table `sales.Customer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your if statement is referencing datecom but there is no query there. Just because this is a trigger you can't just start throwing column names without some kind of reference. You could exists here. Something like this.

```
create trigger detruit_commandes on ArchiveCommandes
for delete 
as 
if exists(select * from inserted where datecom > dateadd(day, -365, getdate()) 
begin 
    raiserror('Suppression des clients et de leurs commandes interdite', 16, 1)
    rollback transaction --I would urge not to use a rollback in your trigger. This can wreak havoc on calling applications. Raise the error and let it bubble back up.
end
begin
    delete a
    from ArchiveClient a 
    join deleted d on a.nocli = d.nocli
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your explication now I will not forget to make a query before, it works